# How can $x^2y''-3xy'+3y=0$ be solved?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

a) How does $x^2y''-3xy'+3y=0$ can be solved? I know how to solve for constant coefficients, but in this case they are functions...

b) In which maximum interval there is a solution that  confirms $y'(1)=6, y(1)=4$?

Comment: This is an example of an *Euler equation*. Googling for that should bring useful information.

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Alvarez why $e^{αt}$ would be the guess, on the rhs there is zero and not something with $e^x$, and does complex numbers come in? may you please give more detail on how to solve this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: This is Euler-Cauchy type equation, so let:

$$y = x^m \implies y' = m x^{m-1} \implies y'' = m(m-1)x^{m-2}$$

Substitute back into ODE, solve for roots, write the general solution and then find constants from initial conditions.

**Spoiler**

> $\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad y(x) = x(x^2 + 3)$

Comment: what guides you to choose $y=x^m$?

Comment: You choose $y=x^m$ because derivative you take lowers the exponent by one. Because each derivative is multiplied by a term of the same order, you wind up with every term having some multiple of $x^m$ after everything is simplified.

Comment: The spoiler to the rescue!

Answer (score 2):

An equation of the form $ax^2u''+bxu'+cu=0$ can be rewritten in terms of the operator $D=x\frac{d}{dx}$: indeed, we have $$ax^2u''+bxu'+cu=aD^2u+(b-a)Du+cu.$$

The right hand side is the result of applying the operator $aD^2+(b-a)D+c$ to $u$. If we are able to factor $aD^2+(b-a)D+c=\alpha(D-\beta)(D-\gamma)$, then we are left with trying to solve the equation $$(D-\beta)(D-\gamma)u=0.$$. Now it is clear that if we manage to find a function such that $$(D-\gamma)u=0$$ we will have a solution, and this equation is $xu'=\gamma u$, which can easily be solved because its variables are separable. Likewise, we can find a solution to out original problem by looking for solutions of $$(D-\beta)u=0.$$ If $\beta\neq\gamma$ in this way we obtain two linearly independent solutions to our original equation.

Comment: All this should be explained in any sensible textbook on ODEs. Moreover, this equation is a very special case of the so called second order ODEs with regular singular points, and the method I sketched is the corresponding special case of the general Frobenius method of solving these equations.

Answer (score -1):

$$am^2+(b-a)m+c=0\\
m^2-4m+3=0\\
(m-3)(m-1)=0\\
m_1=3, \, m_2=1\\
m_1 \neq m_2 \text{ so}\\
Y=C_1X^3+C_2X^1   \text{ is general solution}$$