# Calculate the general solution for this ODE: $x^2y''-3xy'+3y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve for the following ODE and would like the communities support on helping my figure it out:

$x^2y''-3xy'+3y=0$
I have substituted $y = x^k$ into the equation and then taking the derivative until second-order.

1. $y' = kx^{k-1}$
2. $y'' = k(k-1)x^{k-2}$

After doing this I have placed this into the equation to get:

1. $$x^2k(k-1)x^{k-2}-3kxx^{k-1}+3x^k = 0$$
2. $$k(k-1)x^k-3kx^k+3x^k=0 \implies k(k-1)-3k+3=0$$

I'm not sure where to proceed from here. I have tried placing this into a quadratic formula and got:

$$\frac{3k\pm\sqrt{(3k)^2-4(k(k-1))(3)}}{2(k(k-1))}$$

Though I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: 2. implies $k(k-1)-3k+3=0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can $x^2y''-3xy'+3y=0$ be solved?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726650/how-can-x2y-3xy3y-0-be-solved)

Comment: Aha! I forgot to expand before taking the quadratic formula